# Как проверить лист на наличие обьекта с конкретными характеристиками\параметрами? Python

Tags: python

Каждое значение в листе 1 и 2 имеют характеристики которые могут принимать различные числовые значения. Я хочу проверить есть ли в листе1 обьект из листа2 с конкретными характеристиками

```
l1= [[a,b,c,x,y,z],[a,b,c,x,y,z],[a,b,c,x,y,z],...]
l2= [z,b,c]

while True:
    if ...
        break
```

В if условии мне надо проверить имеется ли в первом листе обьект из второго листа с конкретными значемиями параметров z и b, значение c не играет роли при поиске. Как это может быть сделано ?

**Обновление**

l1 представляет собой лист состоящий из карточек и каждая переменная является кокнретной характеристикой присущей карте, например начало пути(z), конец пути(b), колво карт этого(c) типа и т.д.

l2 это лист который обновляется и каждый раз этому листу присваивается одна карта только с 3 из 6 характеристик: начало, конец и колво.

Основываясь на первых двух переменным на начале(z) и конце(b) нужно проверить имеется ли карта с такими же параметрами в стопке карточек. Кол-во не играет роли.

**Обновление 2**

Допустим

```
l2 = [1,4,20]
```

Как прогнать весь `l1`  и проверить, если ли карта с такими же значениями `z=1` и `b=4` как у карты из `l2`?

Comment: Что именно вы пробовали сделать, и где возникли трудности?

Comment: И кстати, с какой целью для l1 выбрана такая странная структура данных - кортеж из списков? Логичнее было бы наоборот - список кортежей.

Comment: Чтобы l1 был списком, всё, что правее знака "равно" в первой строчке нужно обернуть в ещё одну пару квадратных скобок. А так это не список, а кортеж. Впрочем, на решение это мало влияет. Вы так и не ответили - что именно у вас не получается. Без этого уточнения мы не сможем вам помочь.

Answer (score 2):

Трудно уловить истинный смысл в вопросе. Все спутанно.
На всякий случай делаю два варианта как я понял.

- `res1` - если нужно найти одинаковые `z`, `b`, `c`
- `res2` - если нужно найти одинаковые `z`, `b`

Код:

```
l1= [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16,17,18]]
l2= [18,14,15]
res1 = [ x for x in l1 if l2 == x[5:6]+x[1:3] ]
res2 = [ x for x in l1 if l2 == x[5:6]+x[1:2] ]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы перебрать список l1, используйте конструкцию for ... in ...

Например так:

```
for item in l1:
    здесь выполняем проверку на совпадение
```

2. Чтобы из списка каждой карточки взять только нужные параметры, используйте индексы, вот так:

   l2[0]

Такая конструкция извлечёт из списка l2 только нулевой параметр (в программировании отсчёт идёт не с первого элемента, а с нулевого и только потом идёт первый, второй и т.д.)

3. Чтобы сравнить два параметра используйте оператор ветвления if и оператор сравнения ==

Как ими пользоваться, вы легко найдёте в гугле.

А вообще, я бы посоветовал вам прочитать хотя бы самые основы, прежде чем пытаться решать конкретные задачи.

Answer (score 1):

> Допустим `l2 = [1,4,20]`
>   Как прогнать весь `l1` и проверить, если ли карта с такими же значениями `z=1` и `b=4` как у карты из `l2`?

Для читаемости превратим значения в `l1`, `l2` в [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from collections import namedtuple

Map = namedtuple('Map', 'a,b,c,x,y,z')
l1 = [[a,b,c,x,y,z],[a,b,c,x,y,z],[a,b,c,x,y,z],...]
l2 = [1, 4, 20]

z, b = l2[:2] # reference
found_maps = [m for m in map(Map, l1) if z == m.z and b == m.b]
```

Если достаточно найти только одну подходящую карту:

```
found = next((m for m in map(Map, l1) if z == m.z and b == m.b), None)
```

Перебор заканчивается на первой найдённом элементе, не перебирая всего `l1` списка.

В обоих случаях `if found` можно использовать, чтобы проверить найден ли хотя бы один элемент.

Comment: Возможно я сейчас спрошу глупость, поскольку раньше не работал с namedtuple, но всё-таки - как ваш код учитывает, что l2 и элементы из l1 не соответствуют по структуре? В l2 пропущена часть элементов, и они идут в другом порядке. И я вообще не понимаю, как для него может корректно сработать Map(*l2)

Comment: @Александр: верно подмечено—код как был написан не работал. Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, задача достаточно тривиальна, просто автор нагородил слишком много путанного описания. По сути, нам надо пройти по спискам из списка, и найти тот, в котором присутствцют нужные значения. Решается достаточно просто циклом и условием:

```
l1 = [[1,4,2,7,3,5],[1,8,9,2,5,3,7],[3,2,1,5]]
res = None
for item in l1:
    if 4 in item and 7 in item:
        res = item
```

Результатом будет `res = [1,4,2,7,3,5]`

В определениях автора цикл будет иметь примерно следующий вид (для наглядности отдельные логические выражения взял в скобки):

```
for item in l1:
    if (l2[0] in item) and (l2[1] in item):
        res = item
```

Если надо найти все вхождения в список, то нужно объявить переменную `res` как список и операцию присовения заменить на добавление элемента:

```
res = []
for item in l1:
    if (l2[0] in item) and (l2[1] in item):
        res.append(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте использовать SET

```
set1 = set(l1)
set2 = set(l2)

set1.interconnection(set2)
set2 & set2
```